Is this approach to generating points for the graph of a function that attempts to avoid discontinuities appropriate?
I'm not sure where to ask this question, I'd appreciate being redirected accordingly if need be.
Context
Let's say I have a program that might plot the graph of functions supplied by a user, for example:

f1(x) = 1/x ;
f2(x) = sin(x) ;
f3(x) = (x³ + 2x² + 3x + 4)/x ;
f4(x) = sec(x).

Some of these functions have discontinuities which with the majority of plot libraries (all those I know of and I'm not looking for any others actually) will generate a graph connecting points separated by a discontinuity or extremely distant points due to limit behavior. I would like to avoid this as much as possible so that I can generate something better than the basic rendering.
To illustrate, here is what GnuPlot generates for the functions f1 and f4:


As you can see from these images, it is plotting something weird.
My approach
I want a general (i.e. function-independent) way of dealing with this problem. To counter it, I started from the following two observations, but first let's say I generate the points from a list of x in a fixed range [min .. step .. max] and that I assume that user-entered functions are not piecewise defined. Then

If we encounter a point x₁ such that f(x₁) = NaN (or Infinity, etc.), then the probability that x₁ is a discontinuity point of f is sufficiently high (for example, 1/0). I know that the IEEE standard exists and that there are subtleties, but I don't know enough about it, and I think it's rare enough.

It may be (and is in fact the most likely case) that the range of xs does not contain any discontinuity points of the f function, but spans them. For example, if the range is [ -5.0 .. 0.4 .. 5.0 ] then the point x₁ = 0 will not be encountered, yet it is contained in the real interval.
This will generate two points separated by a discontinuity, and the graph rendering library will connect them, as illustrated in the examples above. Two points separated by a discontinuity are often far apart from the general trend. For example, 1/(-0.2) = -5 and 1/(0.2) = 5 while the very next point will generate 1/0.6 = 1.7. The difference is not very large, but it's possible to make "statistics" out of it.


I think observation 1 is the most obvious. I would rather discuss observation 2.
My idea is the following: after having generated all the points (x, y = f(x)) I calculate the standard deviation of the list of y and I go through the list (x, y) to check if the difference between each successive y exceeds this threshold value, in pseudo-code this verification is simply:
let threshold = stdDev ys

let isJumpToLarge(y₁, y₂) =
    abs (y₂ - y₁) > threshold

In an ideal world, this way of working allows us to check for implicit discontinuities by simply looking at the general behavior of all points.
In this approach, when the condition is met, a new list is initialized, marking the start of a new group of points. The function ends by returning a list of list of point ((double * double) list list using OCaml-like syntax). This would allow different sub-graphs (which each correspond to a piece of the function separated by a discontinuity) to be combined into one in the plot lib without the points of the differend sub-graph being connected.
This method seems to work for many of the functions I have been able to test, except when the functions naturally exhibit some "explosive behavior" or oscillate very strongly in a certain region. Here's the result for the same functions as before:


These images illustrate the expected graphs. More specialized programs, such as GeoGebra or Mathematica, also display such graphs without connecting the wrong dots.
The question
However, just because something seems to work doesn't mean it's a good approach and I'm not a statistician, so my use of "statistics" here is probably not fully developed and can probably be improved. So my question is: is this the right approach in a purely numerical context? If so, how can it be further improved? If not, or too limited, then what are the alternatives?
Other approach
When I looked it up on the internet, all the answers I could find dealt with special cases, and most of the time compare signs. However, comparing sign differences, as suggested here or here in StackOverflow, is not sufficiently general; it's enough for the function to be shifted up or down for the suggested approach to fail.
